# Alias for an aggregate column

Tags: kotlin, orm, kotlin-exposed

I would like to get the average of a column using Kotlin Exposed.

```
object MyTable: IntIdTable("MyTable") {
    val score = integer("score")

val result = MyTable.slice(
        MyTable.score.avg().alias("avg_points")
).first()
```

How do I get the result?

For normal columns I would use

```
result[MyTable.score]
```

But now it is an aggregate with an alias. I've tried

```
result["avg_points"]
```

But that fails. I don't see many public methods on `ResultRow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
First save the average to a variable

```kotlin
val avgColumn = MyTable.score.avg().alias("avg_points")
```

Then get the results as such

```kotlin
val result = MyTable.slice(
                avgColumn
        ).selectAll().first()

val avg = result[avgColumn]
```